# PHP post checkbox value with dropdown menu action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have list of articles and for each of them I have a checkbox like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value"1"/>
   </td>
   <td>TTILE   </td>
   <td>DATE    </td>
   <td>ACTIVITY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value"2"/>
   </td>
   <td>TTILE   </td>
   <td>DATE    </td>
   <td>ACTIVITY</td>
</tr>
```

I have dropdown menu for setting an action for each article like this(`delete,approved,sort.....`):

```
<select class="selectD" name="action" id="action">
   <option value="delete">delete</option>
   <option value="approved">approved</option>
   <option value="noapproved">noapproved</option>
   <option value="sort">sort</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="OK" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="S1" />
```

In the php page I have:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "delete")
{
$selected = $_POST['selectedposts']; //LINE 15
if (count($_POST['selectedposts']) !== 0) // LINE 16
{
foreach($selected as $uid)
{
SQL::DEL("DELETE FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id = ?", $uid);
}

echo "<div class=\"success\">delete success</div>";
}
}
```

**EDIT**: I check my cod and see this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: selectedposts in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\modules\allnews.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: selectedposts in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\modules\allnews.php on line 16
```

How can I set delete/approved/sort action for each article? I mean: how to choose any article with checkbox, choose an action from dropdown and send to page with submit button for delete/approved etc action?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have find the exact answer for your question... But for this ans you need jquery first dowload it and store in folder named js in your current program folder

html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="my.php" method="post">
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value"1"/>
   </td>
   <td>TTILE   </td>
   <td>DATE    </td>
   <td>ACTIVITY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value"2"/>
   </td>
   <td>TTILE   </td>
   <td>DATE    </td>
   <td>ACTIVITY</td>
</tr>
<select class="selectD" name="action" id="action">
   <option value="delete">delete</option>
   <option value="approved">approved</option>
   <option value="noapproved">noapproved</option>
   <option value="sort">sort</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="false">
<input type="submit" value="OK" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="S1" />
</form>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').click(function() {

document.getElementById('name').value="false";
$(".check:checked").each(function() {
    document.getElementById('name').value="true";
});



    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

php file: (my.php)

```
<?php
if ($_POST['action'] == "delete")
{
    if($_POST['name']=="true")
    {
if (count($_POST['selectedposts']) != 0)
{
$selected = $_POST['selectedposts'];
foreach($selected as $uid)
{
SQL::DEL("DELETE FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id = ?", $uid);
}
echo "<div class=\"success\">delete success</div>";
}
}
else {
    echo "Nothing selected to delete";
}
}?>
```

for further queries comment below.if it satisfies you, dont forget to accept and upvote the ans

Comment: @EricFavoni finally i have find the exact answer for your question... But for this ans you need jquery first dowload it and store in folder named js in your current program folder.. i edited my ans check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value"1"/>
   </td>
   <td>TTILE   </td>
   <td>DATE    </td>
   <td>ACTIVITY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value"2"/>
   </td>
   <td>TTILE   </td>
   <td>DATE    </td>
   <td>ACTIVITY</td>
</tr>

<!-- Only do this form once, not for every row! -->
<form action="yourphpfile.php" method="post">
    <select class="selectD" name="action" id="action">
        <option value="delete">delete</option>
        <option value="approved">approved</option>
        <option value="noapproved">noapproved</option>
        <option value="sort">sort</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(count($_POST['selectedposts']) > 0){
    if($_POST['action'] == 'delete'){
        delete_posts($_POST['selectedposts']);
    }
    //Your other if-statements
}

function delete_posts($array){
    $ids = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $ids[] = $value;
    }

    //Use PDO for your deletion
    $db = new PDO(...); //Use YOUR PDO instantiation
    $inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
        "DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id IN (" . $inQuery . ")"
    );

    $stmt->execute(array_values($ids))
}
```

I haven't tested it, but see where that gets you!

Comment: i think.In your and my code, form send only action value `(delete, approved ..etc)` not action + selectpost value. please see my error in edit Q.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking to see which checkbox is checked and then use switch cases on them  , I just knocked up a basic demo of what i mean you'll be able to make your own working code after seeing how this works, the only thing was that the value in your select options of `sort` is a PHP keyword so i changed it to `sortthem`.

```
<?php 
function getActionFromSelect($option){
    switch($option){
        case "delete": 
            // ur delete query
            echo "delete article "; 
            break;
        case "approved":
            // your approved query
            echo "approve article"; 
            break;
        case "noapproved":
            // your noapproved query
            echo "noapprove article"; 
            break;
        case "sortthem": 
            // your sortthem query
            echo "sort article "; 
            break;
        default:
            // default query but as you know what the 
            // values are going to be a little unneeded 
            // but its good practice to have it anyway  
            echo "default article query"; 
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST['Chk1'])){
    $article = $_POST['Chk1'];
    $option = $_POST['select1'];

    $action = getActionFromSelect($option);
    echo $action, ' ', $article;

}elseif(!empty($_POST['Chk2'])){
    $article = $_POST['Chk2'];
    $option = $_POST['select2'];

    $action = getActionFromSelect($option);
    echo $action, ' ', $article;

}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="field">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Chk1" name="Chk1" value="1"/>
        <select id="select1" name="select1">
            <option value="delete">delete</option>
            <option value="approved">approved</option>
            <option value="noapproved">noapproved</option>
            <option value="sortthem">sort</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="field">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Chk2" name="Chk2" value="2"/>
        <select id="select2" name="select2">
            <option value="delete">delete</option>
            <option value="approved">approved</option>
            <option value="noapproved">noapproved</option>
            <option value="sortthem">sort</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Edited the `switch` into a function to shorten the amount of code needed